# How Blockchain technology verifies proof of work

Tags: java, blockchain, bitcoin

I am learning Blockchain with some online examples.
I have this high level code where I am creating a new Block with previous hash and then am adding a transaction to it and then generating a difficult hash (with 8 leading zeros) of the block

```
 Block block1 = new Block(previousHash);
 block1.addTransaction(new SomeTransaction());
 block1.mineBlock(difficulty);
 blockchain.add(block1);


public void mineBlock(int difficulty) {
    String target = StringUtil.getDificultyString(difficulty); //Create a string with difficulty * "0"
    while(!hash.substring( 0, difficulty).equals(target)) {
        nonce ++;
        hash = calculateHash();
    }
    System.out.println("Block Mined!!! : " + hash);
}
```

This works well. But I have a question that how this proof of work is verified before adding a block to blockchain.

i.e.
Suppose have generated a hash with 8 leading zeros

```
000000005ed2248f32d7f2509e6291a998a6119b96b1227d27fe03cf21b8c908
```

How will blockchain ensure that this hash is actually a valid hash and not just a random sequence of characters with 8 leading zeros?

Comment: With the help of previous hash and nonce value?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to compute the hash based on the previous block and the nonce you discovered. There is no need for a loop, just one hash computation, which is fast.
So when you add the new block to the chain, you also publish the nonce, and they just compute the hash -- that's the proof of work.

Answer (score 0):

Verification is easy.

It is a one-step process, verifier takes the block header provided by the miner which has nonce proof in it, and passes it through the PoW puzzle. It checks if the output hash is the same as provided by the miner and is less than the threshold to be valid.

In Proof Of Work, **Work is the computation done** by the miner for calculating hash trying the different value of the nonce. And the **Proof is the nonce value** for which it got a valid hash less than the difficulty threshold.

> How will blockchain ensure that this hash is actually a valid hash and not just a random sequence of characters with 8 leading zeros?

This is tricky as in PoW **nonce value is the actual proof of computation work done by the miner** and not the block hash. The difficulty threshold is public so anyone can just write down a random valid hash that is mathematically less than this threshold value and publish it but this won't work because the verification process will still need nonce to verify proof and must be provided by the miner. Thus the miner is left with no choice but to calculate the nonce.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Answer** - Check if

1. Validating if hash is computed correctly for current block
2. Block hash is prefixed with no of zero's greater than or equal to difficulty.

   ```
   // Validating if hash is computed correctly for current block
       String hash = currentBlock.calculateHash();
       if(!currentBlock.hash.equals(hash)) {
           System.out.println("hash is computed incorrectly");
           return false;
       }

   // Validate if block is mined correctly
      if(!currentBlock.hash.substring(0, difficulty).equals(hashTarget)) {
          System.out.println("This block hasn't been mined");
          return false;
      }
   ```

I have explained it in detail in below article along with source code. Please have a look.

[Create your first (very) basic blockchain with Proof of Work](https://medium.com/@mankenavenkatesh/dummychain-tutorial-1-ef7048f3df8f)